# what's wrong to my extra hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive

i'm adding some hard disk on my computer.when i on my computer the extra hard disk was detected by my computer but when i open My Computer the extra hard disk was not on there. What happen?

Comment: Was the hard drive detected by your BIOS? Maybe windows/linux just didn't mount it automatically? I need some more information, what operating system are you using?

Comment: my hard drive did not detected my my BIOS only my primary hard disk was detected.my extra hard disk(secondary) was label No Jumper=DS(SLAVE)..what does it mean?

Comment: i use ELITE motherboard..i think my extra hard disk is not compatible by my motherboard..

Comment: my processor is Intel(R) Pentium (R) D CPU 3.00GHz

Comment: Please add this info to your question :)

Comment: Paul,  please describe (in detail) how you have this disk connected to your motherboard.  Is it hooked to the second IDE channel by itself?  Is it connected to the primary IDE channel at the end of the cable or in the middle?

Answer (score 6):

It probably needs to be formatted.

1. Right-click on My Computer and select manage
2. Expand out Storage on the left and click on "Disk Management"
3. You should see your new disk located in the bottom-middle pane, probably labled "Disk 1"
4. Right-click your unformatted disk and follow the prompts through the wizard to format it correctly.

Comment: my extra hard disk have only 1 jumper and no pins allowed for the slave..only for master and cable select..can i use it as a master?

Comment: i open disk management but only disk 0 is in there

Comment: my primary hard disk was hook on the middle and the cd drive was hook on the end of the IDE. i unplug the IDE on the cd drive and i replace it with my extra hard disk. but my extra hard disk was label No Jumper=DS(SLAVE) so i use it as a master and i set my primary hard disk as a slave..

Answer (score 3):

Can you see the extra hard disk at the hard drives in Device manager? if yes,then it needs to be formatted.if not simply detect it manually or scan it.

Comment: no..how to scan it?

Comment: scan it with device manager.it should appear after, if succeed